# Java random intersection in a range: unexpected results

Tags: java, math, random, probability

Please consider this piece of code:

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long distinct = IntStream.range(0, 600)
                .map(i -> RANDOM.nextInt(600))
                .distinct()
                .count();

        System.out.println("intersection %:" + (double) (600 - distinct) / 600 * 100);
    }
```

I'm generating a random int in a range of (0-600) 600 times, naively expecting to have 0% intersection. Real results are ~ 37%.

Is there a math formula to calculate intersection probability, having range of random ints and the number of invocations? I don't really like to trust this empirical 37% on my calculations

Comment: As Java's Random has an uniform distribution, you should expect the intersections to be 1 in 600.

Comment: Why do you expect to have 0% intersection? If you roll a dice 6 times, do you expect to roll each number exactly once? I would expect to roll some numbers at least twice and some numbers not at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's `Random.nextInt()` is guaranteed to have an uniform distribution, not to be unique everytime you call it.

Thus, the intersection probability is the same kind of calculation than the birthday problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). I'm sorry I don't have the whole formula from the top of my head, but it might be easily found with a little research (or even calculating yourself).

EDIT2 :

The wikipedia page already contained everything you needed :
Look at the part collision counting.